# Call Generic Handler on Page Load in c# (Without Using Javascript)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to call a generic handler (.ashx) on page load without using javascript. Anybody suggest me with an Example.

why i m asking stupid question basically when i call a .aspx page its taking time to load. so i thought if i call handler on page load so that page will be load and data will come after page load.

if u have better solution then pls suggest me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Calling a generic handler will not make the page run faster though.  The only way to make it run faster is to optimize the code or to switch to using JavaScript to loading certain areas of data.

Answer (score 1):

You can potentially use anything with a "source" attribute to call another URL, though it's not a particularly "nice" approach.

In your case you'd need to use an iframe. Maybe if your data is in a table that needs loading, you could embed the iframe with a source to your data. This way your page can load and the iframe part can load when it's ready.

You might do well, however, to reconsider why your not using JavaScript. If you can find a way to use it then you'll be able to create a better user experience.